# Error while updating to database : Oracle

Tags: c#

I am working in .Net Windows Application. In App.Config i had given the connection string like this...

```
<add connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.101)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=PROD)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id=TEST;Password=TEST;" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" name="ConnectionString" />
```

I am doing a update process. Once the breakpoint reaches the update method, i am getting the message like this..

> ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

What should i do for this...

My tnsnames.ora is,

```
PROD =  (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = Prod)
)
```

)

Comment: check tnsnames.ora file for the entry for this database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I remember when we want to specify a connection string for an Oracle connection, the service name should be provided and the rest of information will be loaded from that service name. As Romil said in the comment, you have to make a Service Name in tnsnames.ora. There is a GUI tool for creating the service names. A Service Name is a connection specifier conceptually that everything needed for the connection will be provided in it.
Use this to get more info :
[Quick Start to Oracle Net Connections](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/network.920/a96580/gettings.htm)

Comment: You can very well work _without_ a tnsnames.ora file. I'm doing a pure app.config connection to an Oracle DB.

Comment: It should be ok! Can you connect to your Oracle server using SQL+ with this service name ?! A restart may be needed if you have setup a new one recently, I think.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an example, this is a connection string I'm using in an ASP.NET 4.0 application to connect to an Oracle database through the ODP.NET providers/drivers:

```
<add 
    name="oraOdpNet" 
    connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.101)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE))); User Id=TEST; Password=TEST" 
    providerName="system.data.oracleclient" />
```

I wanted to absolutely *not* depend on an external "tnsnames.ora" file.

Comment: @RobinHood Are you sure that you are actually accessing the connection string (which you named "`ConnectionString`") in your code?